# Python base class initializes other classes depending on argument

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have two classes that take the same parameters and do the same job, using different methods.

```
class SquareMethodA:
    def __init__(self, some_parameter):
        self.some_parameter = some_parameter
    
    def compute(self, x):
        return x ** 2

class SquareMethodB:
    def __init__(self, some_parameter):
        self.some_parameter = some_parameter
    
    def compute(self, x):
        return x * x
```

Then I have a base class that acts as a high-level user API.
Depending on the user provided "method" argument, the BaseClass initializes either of the two and returns the result.

Currently I do it like below

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, some_parameter, method = 'A'):
        self.method = method
        self.some_parameter = some_parameter
        
        if method == 'A':
            self.instance = SquareMethodA(self.some_parameter)
        elif method == 'B':
            self.instance = SquareMethodB(self.some_parameter)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'{method} is not a valid method.')

    def compute(x):
        return self.instance.compute(x)
```

Therefore the user only initializes the class Square with optional method argument to determine the method of computation.
What is the most proper way to do this, perhaps using some form of inheritance?

Comment: `Square` is not a base class. There is no inheritance going on here, instead, there is composition (which is fine, but just to keep the terminologies straight)

Comment: Probably, you just simply don't need your `Square` class or inheritance. Instead, it can just be a function, `def create_square(method): ... ` and then based on your conditional, it either returns `SquareMethodA` or `SquareMethodB`. This is like the `open` function, which returns some instance of a type of IO class depending on the `mode` argument

Comment: Even though they are simplified here, both SquareMethodA and SquareMethodB must be initialized first before use in real-life. So I cannot bypass the initialization of the Square class here. Although, I am open to any kind of elegancy that would improve the current code. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It looks like you're implementing the Factory design patter.

Comment: What you are saying seems to not be related to anything I'm saying. And generally speaking, any object must be initialized before it can be used. That is *just normal*. You absolutely *can just remove the `Square` class here*. Simply make it a function that returns either `SquareMethodA(some_parameter)` or `SquareMethodB(some_parameter)` or raises a ValueError

Comment: @Barmar right, just typically in Python, you'd simply use a function. There's no point in writing a wrapper class to just proxy out to a single method. Just return an instance of the appropriate class from a factory function based on the arguments e.g. like `open`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a factory function:

```
def create_square(some_parameter, method = 'A'):        
    if method == 'A':
        return SquareMethodA(some_parameter)
    elif method == 'B':
        return SquareMethodB(some_parameter)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'{method} is not a valid method.')

my_square = create_square("foo", method="B")
print(my_square.compute(42))
```